# Remove SharePoint from IIS Website (Default)

Tags: 2010, iis, alternate-access-mapping

i have created web application and also successfully extended with Windows Authentication,

- Default zone on port 80 and
- Internet zone on port 80 (anonymous)

so i got two web site in IIS (Internal and External)

I have also setup the AAM for both which tested ok after updating hostfile. 
But now if i want to change the url of both which i know i can remove extended Web Application (External) using

- CA > Selected Web App > Delete > Remove SharePoint from IIS Web Site (External) > Delete IIS web site

So in order to have new extended web application with new host name is it ok if i remove internal IIS website ?

- CA > Selected Web App > Delete > Remove SharePoint from IIS Web Site (Internal) ? Delete IIS web site which uses Default zone ?

if yes, Will i still be able to extend the Web Application with new host name and public url?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want new URL for the default and internet zone? In IIS did you check the bindings for the website?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of deleting IIS Websites, causing production stop - I'd suggest creating additional Alternate Access Mappings. You have five zones which only differs by their name.

That way you can test your new URLs in parallel with the old ones, before going "live". Don't forget to add binding on the new websites though.

Comment: Thanks Benny, i have added new AAM with Internet Zone which works. I can access the site, but for some strange reason it the site shows as site actions means its not anonymous anymore. i m now thinking of un-extending external site and then start with new Web App extension with new host name matching the DNS entry.

Comment: sorry forgot to mentioned this is still pre-prod.

Comment: So the problem remains even after unextending and extending same web with port 80, new host name, internet zone, the site still shows AD name. please assist.

Comment: ok, i can now access both zone=default (internal site) internally and zone=internet (external site) anonymously tested with adding host file.